# Find distribution of Y-X from joint density of x and y

Tags: probability-theory

Question from Gut's An Intermediate Course of Probability - Chapter 1 - Problem 22;

- X and Y have a joint distribution.

  f(x,y) = \begin{cases} cx(y-1),  & \text{0 < x < y < 1} \\
  0, & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}

Determine the distribution of Y-X.

My approach:

- Usually, in question where two parameter (for example, Y-X and 2Y+X) is wanted, I define two parameter U = Y-X and W = 2Y+X for them and define X and Y depending on U and W. However, I could not be sure what to do when there is only one parameter. Also, should I try to find c or will it vanish through calculations?

Thank you all!

Comment: Take $U=X-Y, V=X$.

Comment: I thought, but then I will again have joint distribution of U and V. You say "Take U and V and separate them" ?

Comment: To find $c$ you normalize: $ 1 = \int \int p(x,y) dx dy$. To find the distribution of $z=y-x$, you integrate $ p(z) = \int \int \delta(z-[y-x])p(x,y)dx dy$

Comment: If you know the joint pdf of $U$ and $V$ you get the pdf of $U$ by integrating the pdf w.r.t. $v$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @kevinkayaks has commented, to find $c$ calculate the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f$ and equal it to $1$. That gives you
$$c=-24.$$
To determine the distribution of $Z=Y-X$, we first find its distribution function
\begin{align*}F_Z(z)&=\text{P}[Z\leq z]\\
&=\text{P}[(X,Y)\in\{(x,y):y\leq z+x\}]\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{z+x}f(x,y)dydx.\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}f_Z(z)&=F'_Z(z)\\&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x,z+x)dx.\end{align*}
You have to study now the inequalities $0<x<z+x<1$ to find the integral above.

**EDIT.** These inequalities will hold only when $0<z<1$. Therefore,
\begin{align*}f_Z(z)&=-24\int_{0}^{1-z}x(z+x-1)dx\\
&=4(1-z)^3.\end{align*}
So, $f_Z$ is the above expression for $0<z<1$ and is $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: Can you please extend this to full solution? I need to see one solution to have a clear sight.

Comment: Of course I can! You're welcome.

Comment: Life saver before midterm!